# Issue while converting string to datetime in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am having dataframe like

**Input**

```
Date
2020-12-21
2019-09-30
2019-12-04
```

I want to convert this specific date time format.

**Expected Format**

```
       Date
    2020-12-21T00:00:00Z
    2019-09-30T00:00:00Z
    2019-12-04T00:00:00Z
```

My current code

```
df.loc[:,'Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'Date'])
```

Its not working correctly. How can this be fixed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Its not working correctly". Do you get an error or an unexpected result?

Comment: @PeptideWitch, I am  not getting  timestamp in this way `T00:00:00Z`

Comment: @PeptideWitch, I want to get the timestamp in this format `T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Do you need the datetime properties or the string format? Given your format just add 'T00:00:00Z' to the strings if the later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a shortcut for ISO time format. Here's a hack around:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Output:

```
0    2020-12-21T00:00:00Z
1    2019-09-30T00:00:00Z
2    2019-12-04T00:00:00Z
Name: Date, dtype: object
```